# Running stored procedure through Service

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

Ok so this code was written by someone else and is running perfectly fine on the server, but I have to set it up on my machine to make some changes and when I debug this code on my machine, I get the following error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

The code is actually running a stored procedure.

```
CIServiceClient serviceClient = new CIServiceClient();
serviceClient.GetProjectCodesAsync();
serviceClient.GetProjectCodesCompleted += new EventHandler<GetProjectCodesCompletedEventArgs>(serviceClient_GetProjectCodesCompleted);

serviceClient.GetAllConsultantsAsync();
serviceClient.GetAllConsultantsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetAllConsultantsCompletedEventArgs>(serviceClient_GetAllConsultantsCompleted);
```

I have no idea as to what exactly is going on. Specially because it is running on the server and not on my machine. What am I missing here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should post all your code, specifically code related to establishing a connection to the database.

Comment: That looks like client side WCF code - this calls the generated proxy which then cals the actual web service which then makes your database call.

Comment: Thank you for your comment William. You prompted me to check my connection string, and thats where the problem was.